# Trying to use the ProtectedData Class in C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, using

I am trying to implement the  ProtectedData Class in C++ but are having some issues with compilation. My first error comes from not being able to use `#using <System.Security.dll>`. The error is that IntelliSense: "#using" requires C++/CLI to be enabled, however when I go into my project settings and set the common language runtime support to /clr, In my project I do not see my sytax errors getting corrected anymore. I then thought ok this must have fixed all the issues but then i go to compile and then I receive and error that '/clr' and '/Gm' command-line options are incompatible. So i go to look at this and I am not sure what to put to correct my problem. Is there any way I can use the ProtectedData Class without having to go through the different config process?

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.

The link to the ProtectedData Class is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's C++/CLI, not true C++.  You'll have to make a CLI project.

Comment: @Mooing Duck If I make a CLI project, can I then import from this? In other words can I use the protectedData class this way?

Comment: I don't know anything about what you're doing, because it's C++/CLI.  I only know C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express instead. C++/CLI is best used only as a .NET/native bridging framework, and only when other methods of interoperation aren't suitable (such [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)).

If you decide to use C++, you do need to use the /CLR switch. Although you can tweak a C++ project into a C++/CLI project, it's best to start fresh with the one of the CLR project templates.

Two ways to indicate that you want to use an external .NET assembly:

1. specify it with `#using`, or
2. add it to the References section of the project properties

Since you mentioned Intellisense, you'll find that it's not supported in C++/CLI code.

Comment: Great thanks for the excellent explanation. I truly appreciate it. I will try to go your route.